# ActionScript3: Making enemy fly when hit

Tags: flash, actionscript, collision, game-physics

i want to be able to make my enemy kind of fly and fall on the ground (to show the power of the punch)to get up again.hero is my main character villain is AI. hero frame 5 is punch animation.

```
if(hero.hitTestObject(villain)&& hero.currentFrame==5&& hero.scaleX==-1 &&hit==true){

        villain.gotoAndPlay('tdt');
        villain.x-=100;
        movingl=false;
        movingr=false;

    }
  else if(hero.hitTestObject(villain)&& hero.currentFrame==5&& hero.scaleX==1){

        villain.gotoAndPlay('tdt');//villain damaged frame
        villain.x+=200;
        villain.y-=10;
        movingl=false;//if AI moves left 
        movingr=false;//if AI moves right

    }
             else{
        villain.gotoAndStop('vstill');
    }
```

but 2 things don't work:

1)target fly's of when animation starts not on punch(tried to use current frame to access Movie Clip within Movie Clip to get to the specific frame but got this in output

TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties).

2)villain gets up to fast and animation changes in mid air and starts running due to the moving AI code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make it simpler
use and `ENTER_FRAME` event as a detector and then go there and say whenever the health of your character gets lower than 50 for example, go to your falling function.
you can set your loop function to do the falling action only once.

Comment: Thanks figured it out

Answer (score 0):

I can observe that you are making a complete collision detection on both objects, which makes me think about some other problems on your game:
- you are not taking into account that those methods are not perfect: [try reading this](http://sierakowski.eu/list-of-tips/39-collision-detection-methods-hittest-and-hittestobject-alternatives.html)
- if it is a fight game, you are also not taking if those objects are touching because of the hitting action, or merely because they were simply touching (like in two characters colliding back to back without a fighting effective action).

I am also seeing that although you are planning to write AS3, you are pretty much doing things the AS2 way still with methods like gotoAndPlay.

We still need a lot more information on how your entire MovieClips and swf files are structured to be able to debug it. Or post the relevant part of your project to be able to debug it inside Flash.

Comment: sorry but im a total noob to counter the hit test method i added the current frame statement what would you suggest.

Comment: i am trying to make a game similar to this http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/510744

Comment: You can try coding into Starling over one existant 2D framework like Flixel... which is a very nice engine: flixel.org
Or you can try higher level engines like Unity 3D, Game Maker or Construct2 and export into Flash (and more platforms). And those are free.

Comment: for hit test should i use invisible hit boxes for accuracy and would you know any tutorials. thanks

Comment: the use case of hit test is not meant for the accuracy needed in games, but rather for simple interactive products. The correct way of implementing this the modern AS3 way would be by using the Starling framework: http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/solved-pixel-perfect-collision-detection-between-2-movieclip-in-starling

But it is very advanced for what I understand for your needs. That is why I recommend using a game development framework.